# Large formula in align

Tags: equations, align

I have a large formula in align:

```
\begin{align*}
log \mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,...,l_n)&=\\\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right) \right) 
\end{align*}
```

Currently, this looks like

[image: te]

But I want to have the first equation, the logL a bit pushed to the left. Now it is on the right side, what I don't like. I tried to insert a & before the exp to align it on that point, but this does not work.

```
 \begin{align*}
    log \mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,...,l_n)&=\\\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} &exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right) \right) 
    \end{align*}
```

How can I get the first part of the equation aligned in the center?

Comment: You don't need align for a single equation... maybe the `{multline}` environment is better here, see [`mathmode`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode) for reference.

Comment: And how can I solve my problem? What code should I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To obtain a centred "first part" and only have two parts, I assume you just want the whole things centred. For this you just have to `gather*` the contents:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \log \mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,...,l_n) = \\
  \sum_{i=1}^n  \left( \log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} \exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right) \right)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\log` as an operator for logarithm.

Comment: thanks, but what is the difference between \log and log? I like the cursive log?

Comment: @JenBohold: `\log` prints `log` as an operator in upright font. `log` in math mode is similar to the multiplication of three variables `l`, `o` and `g`. The same goes for `\exp` (multiplication of `e`, `x` and `p`).

Answer (score 8):

This is how it looks with `multline*` (just to let you know):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
  \log\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,...,l_n)=\\
  \sum_{i=1}^n  \left(\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha\delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} \exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right)\right)
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd use this way rather than centering.

Comment: +1 Other tweaks: spacing around `|`, size of brackets (particularly the one after `\exp`) and their spacing.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thanks, but adding `\mid` and substituting `\left` and `\right` with correct sizes was not the aim of the last edit.

Answer (score 3):

Just to comment on Karls suggestion, this is how I normally do this in order to get a more consistent look and feel. Note that the `=` is moved to the next line (this is generally a good idea it it may be overlooked overwise)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % autoloads amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft\log\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,\dots,l_n)
 \\
  &=\sum_{i=1}^n  \left(\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha
    \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} \exp\left(-\alpha
  \sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right)\right)
 \end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

`\MoveEqLeft` has a hidden `&` inside it, and will pull the line `2em` backwards from the alignment point.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This `stackengine` solution has two features to note:  1) you can customize the gap between the lines (currently set to 10pt); and 2) you can choose the alignment of the equations, relative to each other (currently set centered "l", but can be set to "c" or "r").

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackMath
\def\stackalignment{l}
\stackanchor[10pt]{\displaystyle%
  \log\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,...,l_n)=
}{\displaystyle
  \sum_{i=1}^n  \left(\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha\delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} \exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right)\right)
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\stackMath` macro is recently introduced to the `stackengine` package, and causes the stacking arguments to be processed in `\textstyle` math by default.

Answer (score 0):

Check with the below tag:

```
\begin{gather}
log \mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta,\mu,\delta|  l_1,...,l_n)=\\
\sum_{i=1}^n  \left( log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2}}{2\alpha \delta K_1 (\delta\sqrt{\alpha^2-\beta^2})} exp\left(-\alpha\sqrt{\delta^2+(l-\mu)^2}+\beta(l-\mu)\right)\right) \right) 
\end{gather}
```